# Why we have api folder in Next.js app with MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, rest, mongoose, next.js

I'm doing Next.js e-commerce project with MongoDB. I took as a basis example project "with-mongodb-mongoose" from GitHub (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose). All works fine, but I can't understand why we have api folder with GET, PUT etc routes? If I will delete this folder all works anyway cause in components we use mongodb methods like find, findById etc and don't using routes from api.

Thanks for explanation and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that the api route's name is [id] and hence it's dynamic. This means that you could fetch "/pets/123" for example, and the route would extract that id '123' from the request url paramater, like this:

```
const {
query: { id },
method,
} = req
```

and then fetch that specific animal: `const pet = await Pet.findById(id)`

This enables you to fetch specific pets by fetching only the ones with the id from the url and not all pets in general like the index.js file.

You can delete the file if you don't need to fetch specific pets by id, but I guess it's there to show you how nextjs dynamic api routes work.

As you said the form component uses the dynamic route to fetch an animal by id, so if you remove that folder you'll lose that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Yes, I understood what you mean, but for individual pet I can make folder "pets" in pages and make [id].js file inside "pets". Inside of [id].js getServerSideProps I will do something like this: `const pet = await Pet.findById(params.id).lean()`
So, api folder isn't necessary yet.

Comment: getServerSideProps is used to fetch initial data which should be initially displayed and rendered by the server. So you can fetch an individual pet with getServerSideProps ONCE per page, but if you'd like the user to request more individual pets without having to reload and rerender the page, you'd need an API route, because once the site has been rendered and sent to the client, the user will not have access to the database connection on the front-end anymore since getServerSideProps only runs once on server-side, not client-side.